# unable to replace ')' in a string with ')\n'

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to display my input in a new line whenever i see an entry with `),`

Actual input:

```
 (brb = 0069 of Clinic = Clinic Name 006uh9)(brb = 07hvh03 of Clinic =    

 Clinic 0703)(brb = 0703 of Clinic = Clinic1)
```

expected output:

```
 (brb = 0069 of Clinic = Clinic Name 006uh9)
 (brb = 07hvh03 of Clinic =    Clinic 0703)
```

whenever i am doing string.replaceAll() it  is saying

```
'/) no match found' error.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
 errorMsgArray.push(errorMsg);

 if(errorMsgArray.length > 0){

   for(i=0;i<errorMsgArray.length;i++){
            var arr=errorMsgArray[i].split(',');                                                                                                                                                                                   
             for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

               errorMessage+="("+"brb = "+arr[i]+")";
               finalMessage =errorMessage.replace('[',"");
               finalMessage = finalMessage.replace(']',"");                                                                       

           finalMessage=finalMessage.replaceAll('-',"of Clinic = ");                                                              
           $("#forceUpdateMsg").text(finalMessage + " is/are within zip  
          code " + inputData.updatedBy + " and will be changed to zip  
          code " + inputData.zipCode + ".  Proceed (Y/N)?"
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: So where is your code that doesn't work?

Comment: *"I am doing string.replaceAll()"* - JavaScript doesn't have a string `.replaceAll()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var s= YourString.replace(')',')\n')
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is `(...)(...)(...)` and you want to insert `\n` between `)` and `(`, you should use a regular expression.

```
var input = "(hjj = 0069 of Clinic = Clinic Name 006uh9)(bjb = 07hvh03 of Clinic = Clinic 0703)(vhvh = 0703 of Clinic = Clinic1)"
var output = input.replace(/\)\(/g, ')\n(')

console.log(output)
```

In the regexp, you should escape `(` and `)` as they are metacharacters.

Comment: @Rajesh i have forgot to paste my code, that doesnot mean there isnt any effort!!!!!

Comment: I don't think that I have to be so picky. In his question, he tried to use `replaceAll` and got error message.

Comment: @mohanbabu how will we know if you have invested any effort if you forgot to **show** us?

Comment: @Rajesh I have seen my mistake but in the process of correcting it donot put the same comment for every answer it is very offensive

Comment: @mohanbabu Please take this as a lesson that sharing efforts is very important and not sharing will not only bring downvotes but also comments like those. Also lets not span comments section. I deleted those comments as soon as you added code :-)